# Is the dynamo db scan smart to query only the partition if the scan's filter contains the partition key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

To search data in dynamodbb table there are 2 options:

1. Scan
2. Query

Scan searches the whole table where as query uses the concept of partition key to search through only the partition containing the given key.

Both options also support using filter. Is the dynamo db **scan** option smart to notice whether the filter contains the partition key and if so then use the search only in the given partition or does it still use the scan approach where-in entire table is scanned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **no** - a `Scan` operation will always read the entire table, and charge you for that read. If you only want to read a single partition you should use `Query` instead.

A `Scan` with a `FilterExpression` involving the partiton key is allowed, but usually only makes financial sense when the filter condition leaves a large percentage of the partitions, and not just a "pk=..." filter which leaves just a single partition.

In general, for both `Scan` and `Query`, you should understand that `FilterExpression` is **always** run after the **unfiltered** data has been read.

Comment: oh so even for the query with specified partition key, the `FilterExpression` is essentially run on application level

Answer (score 1):

There are two major differences to how scans and queries work.

**Data Retrieval**

A scan will perform a lookup across all partitions, whereas a query will lookup only a single partition. Because of this approach the cost of the scan operation will be the RCU for the entire DynamoDB table, whilst a query is more efficient in how it retrieves data.

**Data Filtering**

A scan will perform the filter after the entire dataset has been retrieved, this means even if you filter by partition key it will only perform this filter after the dataset is ready. The query operation performs the filter on the partition itself, this will result in the query operation RCU cost being for only the item(s) returned which is far more cost efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is run after all the data has been retrieved either by the scan or query operation and isn’t applied while the operations is in process. I’d recommend using query whenever you can as it’s quicker and less expensive.